# How do I fix 'Target "process_screenshot" links to: Boost::program_options but the target was not found.'

Tags: c#, c++, cmake, compilation, building

When I try building the [SquadOVNext repository](https://github.com/SquadOV/SquadOVNext), I get this error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at src/tools/process_screenshot/CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "process_screenshot" links to:

    Boost::program_options

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.       C:\Users\PLACEHOLDER\Documents\GitHub\SquadOVNext\src/tools/process_screenshot/CMakeLists.txt   5
```

All the dependencies are installed, and it compiles until this line:

```
target_link_libraries(process_screenshot PRIVATE
    libav
    Boost::program_options
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you use `vcpkg`. What instead you should do is set the [CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE](https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration.html) to point to vcpkg's toolchain, e.g.:

```
cmake -S../my/project -Bbuild -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[vcpkg-root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

Then you can use the `find_package()` to find boost and use predefined variables for your linking and include folders. Take a look at [find_package(Boost)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html).

EDIT: by `[vcpkg-root]` I mean the actual path to your `vcpkg`.

Comment: Turns out that I hadn't installed boost-program-options with vcpkg, and I didn't even need the lines in CMakeLIsts.txt. Thanks!